# Solr : Suggester dictionary build creates huge temporary files

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm using sunspot-solr 2.3.0 for my rails app.
I implemented a suggester (AnalyzingSuggester) on Solr for autocompletion. I have a database of about 11M entries with 5 fields indexed by Solr.

When building the suggestions dictionary, two files are created in my /tmp/ folder:

- **AnalyzingSuggester1784590344675447619.input** (number vary). This file gets bigger and bigger until eventually I have no space left then it seems to disappear ?
- **AnalyzingSuggester8456478182934503596.sorted** (number vary too). This file is 0 kb.

I searched a lot but can't seem to understand what exactly is happening and if / how I should prevent this weird behavior. Is this a normal part of the dictionary build ? Is this just some logging ?

Comment: What is "huge" in actual file size? How big is your index in file size?

Comment: @MatsLindh huge here means "all the space left on my device" which goes to 50go in dev environment or 200go on my production server.

My index seems to weight about 13 go in production (with 317 files in the index folder), the dictionary folder weight 1.8 go with one file. For some reason, in dev environment it's 8go and 1,3go.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my solr 6.0.1. The tmp file blows up indefinitely until the hard drive is full.

My index only contains about 2500 documents.

Search component:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SuggestComponent" name="autoSuggest">
        <lst name="suggester">
            <str name="name">analyzingSuggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="storeDir">analyzing_suggestions</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
            <str name="field">text_suggest_auto</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggestion_auto</str>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>
```

Request handler:

```
<requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" name="/suggestAuto" startup="lazy" >
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="suggest">true</str>
            <str name="suggest.dictionary">analyzingSuggester</str>
            <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
            <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
            <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>autoSuggest</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

Field:

```
<fieldType name="text_suggestion_auto" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            preserveOriginal="1"/>  
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_general.txt" format="snowball" />
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_general.txt" format="snowball" />
            </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```